# Tests doesn't work properly when using @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class) and @PowerMockRunnerDelegate(Parameterized.class)

Tags: java, maven, junit4, powermock, parametrized-testing

When I run `mvn test -Dtest=ClassTest` it works however when I run just `mvn test` it fails because classes that should be mocked by PowerMock are null.

Following some details:

jdk 1.7
mvn 3.6.3

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
   <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
   <version>1.7.4</version>
   <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
   <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito2</artifactId>
   <version>1.7.4</version>
   <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

```
Tests in error: 
  Test.souldExecute:99 NullPointer
  Test.souldExecute:99 NullPointer
  Test.souldExecute:99 NullPointer
```

Comment: Without giving more detailed information it's impossible to even guess... a full test the full error output also upgrade Maven, JDK and plugins ..and reconsider using powermock...

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.